# Running Linkedin's Rest.li example

Tags: java, rest, gradle, linkedin-api, rest.li

I am using the following links as a guide: [1](https://github.com/linkedin/rest.li/wiki/Quickstart%3a-A-Tutorial-Introduction-to-Rest.li) and [2](https://github.com/linkedin/rest.li)

- I downloaded gradle 1.4 - the rest.li source requires 1.2 or higher [1](https://github.com/linkedin/rest.li/wiki/Quickstart%3a-A-Tutorial-Introduction-to-Rest.li). When running `gradle -version` I see the following:

  ```
  Gradle 1.4

  Gradle build time: Monday, January 28, 2013 3:42:46 AM UTC
  Groovy: 1.8.6
  Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
  Ivy: 2.2.0
  JVM: 1.7.0_09 (Oracle Corporation 23.5-b02)
  OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
  ```

  so that part should be ok.
- I downloaded all sources from [2](https://github.com/linkedin/rest.li) and unzipped them.
- I set `RESTLI_HOME=/path-to-restli-source/rest.li` as per [1](https://github.com/linkedin/rest.li/wiki/Quickstart%3a-A-Tutorial-Introduction-to-Rest.li) (not sure if I need to do this - confirmed no need).
- I navigated to `<my path>\rest.li-master\example-standalone-app\api` in command line.
- I performed `gradle build -stacktrace` as per [3](https://github.com/linkedin/rest.li/tree/master/example-standalone-app). Which gives me the following stack trace:

  ```
  Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read         http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
  Deprecated dynamic property: "pegasusVersion" on "root project 'example-standalone-app'", value: "1.8.3".
  Deprecated dynamic property: "spec" on "root project 'example-standalone-app'", value: "{product={pegasus={dat...".
  Deprecated dynamic property: "sourceCompatibility" on "project ':api'", value: "1.6".
  Deprecated dynamic property "sourceCompatibility" created in multiple locations.
  :api:generateAvroSchema UP-TO-DATE
  :api:mainDataModelJar UP-TO-DATE
  :api:generateDataTemplate
  There are 1 data schema input files. Using input root folder: C:\dev\trees\rest.li-master\example-standalone-app\api\src\main\pegasus
  :api:generateDataTemplate FAILED

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':api:generateDataTemplate'.
  > Ambiguous method overloading for method java.net.URLClassLoader#<init>.
  Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class [Ljava.net.URL;, null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
  [class [Ljava.net.URL;, class java.security.AccessControlContext]
  [class [Ljava.net.URL;, class java.lang.ClassLoader]

  * Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  * Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':api:generateDataTemplate'.
  at         org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:72)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:49)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:275)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:38)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:30)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:84)
  at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
  at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:165)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
  at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
  at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
  at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
  Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method java.net.URLClassLoader#<init>.
  Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class [Ljava.net.URL;, null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
  [class [Ljava.net.URL;, class java.security.AccessControlContext]
  [class [Ljava.net.URL;, class java.lang.ClassLoader]
  at com.linkedin.pegasus.gradle.PegasusGeneratorV2Plugin$GenerateDataTemplate.generate(PegasusGeneratorV2Plugin.groovy:1225)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
  at com.linkedin.pegasus.gradle.PegasusGeneratorV2Plugin$GenerateDataTemplate_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:161)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:156)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:510)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:499)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:64)
  ... 57 more


  BUILD FAILED

  Total time: 23.93 secs
  ```
- The problem is with Pegasus, the schema definition generator [4](https://github.com/linkedin/rest.li/wiki/DATA-Data-Schema-and-Templates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile using Java 6, problem was I was using Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

As of pegasus 1.9.5 and later, the build is java 7 compatible.